# Очистка mysql базы от дублей

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база в пару лямов ключей(один ключ: 3-4 слова).То есть таблица с одним всего полем,база растет каждый час.Вопрос: посоветуйте как эффективно очистить базу от дублей?:)

Comment: Эффективнее всего руками разработчика, который допустил дубли в базе, которую придумал сам.

Comment: На днях уже проходил такой вопрос в итоге он ведет сюда: [Как удлить дубли в MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630440/how-to-delete-duplicates-on-a-mysql-table/2630527#2630527)